# How to remove parentheses from string got from array of array in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

```
// Form the query.
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select firstTimeStamp from activityTimeStamp where userId=\"%@\" And buddyId=\"%@\"",[PFUser currentUser].username,buddyId];    
        // Get the results.
        if (self.arrTimeStampInfo != nil) {
            self.arrTimeStampInfo = nil;
        }
        // Getting Data into Array
        self.arrTimeStampInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

       // Get the results.
    if (self.arrTimeStampInfo != nil) {
        self.arrTimeStampInfo = nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"Array containing records%@", self.arrTimeStampInfo);
and it prints (    (1111132324)   ) 
    NSString *string = [_arrTimeStampInfo objectAtIndex: 0];
```

when i print the string it comes like (1111132324) and i want to remove those brackets want only number in the string? Any clue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  // Getting Data into Array
    self.arrTimeStampInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];
    NSArray* firstItem = [self.arrTimeStampInfo objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString* string1 = [firstItem objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Array containing records%@", string1);
    NSInteger a=[string1 intValue];
  NSLog(@"time stamp finally we got = %ld",a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
 NSArray *array = @[@"1111132324"];
 NSLog(@"array : %@", array);
 NSLog(@"array[0] : %@", array[0]);
```

and i get output:

[image]

as you see when I print array it gives output in braces '(' and ')'. If i print just single element of array which is string here, there is no braces.

As you said you have array in array, try like this

```
NSArray *arrayOuter = @[@"1111132324"];
NSArray *arrayInner = @[arrayOuter];

NSLog(@"array : %@", arrayInner);
NSLog(@"array[0] : %@", arrayInner[0]);
NSLog(@"array[0] : %@", arrayInner[0][0]);
```

see output:

[image]

You can extend your hierarchy of dictionary or array or mix of array-dictionary (doesn't matter) upto n times like this.

every key(for dict)/index(for array) is must be in that hierarchy level. Style of getting data is from upper hierarchy to lower hierarchy.

For dictionary

```
dict[@"key1"][@"key2"]...[@"keyN"]
```

for mix dict-arr

```
//upper object must be dictionary so start with key.
dict[@"key1"][0][@"key"]..[@"keyN"] or object index.
```

for mix array - dict

```
//upper object must be array so start with index.
dict[0][@"key1"][@"key"]..[@"keyN"] or object index.
```

**NOTE:** Sequence of key and index is according to the object at that hierarchy.

Comment: Tinu Dahiya i have element in array of array like ((11111))

Comment: perfect :) i have suggested another answer as well. Any way thanks

Comment: look 1 more time for another updated answer for the general purpose @jatoi110